# Deleting a row from the database via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so what I've got here is a PHP generated table in which the values are pulled from a database. Now, if the administrator is logged in, I'd like to add an option to delete a row from the database.

I've got the structure all set up, but I have no idea what to put in the path of the link that is supposed to delete the row. How can I do this?

```
<?php
    $rb = 1;
    include 'konekcija.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM oglasi";
    $rezultat = mysql_query($query);
    while($niz = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)){

        echo "<tr><td>" . $rb . "</td><td>" . $niz['model'] . "</td><td>" . $niz['cena'] . "</td><td><img src='" . $niz['slika_path'] . "'</img></td>";
        if($_SESSION['uloga'] == "admin"){
            echo "<td><a href='#'>Obrisi</a></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $rb++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: So when yous say delete row... Do you mean delete row from html table? Or actually delete row from database when html row is deleted?

Comment: For one thing, you will need `session_start();` since you're using sessions (if it's not inside your include already). `if($_SESSION['uloga'] == "admin")` (*Just saying*) ;-)

Comment: i think you have to create a button for every row and send ajax request on its click to delete row by id.

Comment: [**See this Q&A on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14475096/1415724) which helped me achieve something similar.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to rid it from the database. I've got the session_start() up there, this is just a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?row=" .$niz['id']. "'>Obrisi</a></td>";
```

Where `delete.php` is a php page that checks if the user is an administrator, parses the `id` value via GET (always remember to do proper escaping to avoid injections, or use other query systems, like `prepared statements` or `stored procedures`), and deletes the row with the specified id. Of course every record must have a unique id. Eventually the page redirects to the table view page.

**Important sidenote:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` ones instead!

Comment: If it was, please flag it as helpful! :)

Comment: I don't think I've got enough reputation for that.

Thanks anyway, I'm really grateful.

Comment: pretty nice and concise ^^. too bad it's too exploitable. I wish the internets were as simple as my localhost

Answer (score 0):

Well first of the link that you should use to delete the row is going to be whatever link you create.

Therefore you will have to create a new php page, or modify an existing one. To handle the requests to delete the rows.

Here is a quick example:

handler.php

```
<?php
//execute database connection here
switch($_GET['action'])
{
    case 'delete':
        mysql_query('DELETE FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE '.$_GET['where']);
        break;

    case 'add':
        //parse info and submit request to db
        break;

    case 'edit':
        //parse info and submit request to db
        break;
}
//close db connection
?>
```

*Disclaimer! This example is by no means secure, do not use it in production.*

Then the absolute link you would use would be something like: (unescaped version)
`http://host.com/pathtofile/handler.php?action=delete&where=(`row_name`='rowid')`

Answer (score 0):

guo

```
$rb = 1;
include 'konekcija.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM oglasi";
$rezultat = mysql_query($query);
while($niz = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)){

    echo "<tr><td>" . $rb . "</td><td>" . $niz['model'] . "</td><td>" . $niz['cena'] . "</td><td><img src='" . $niz['slika_path'] . "'</img></td>";
    if($_SESSION['uloga'] == "admin"){
        echo "<td><a href='#'>Obrisi</a></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $rb++;
}
```

?>