# Unable to delete user from checkbox in PHP

Tags: php

i am trying to delete some rows but i dont know where i am mistaking please check this below code and suggest my error with solution:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && $_GET['delete']=="true")
{
     $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
     for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
     {
         echo $checkbox[$i]; // here i am going to write delete query
     }
}
```

Now my HTML code for that. I have created a table for users.

it looks something like this in HTML

```
<table id="sample_2">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th style="width:8px;"><input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_2 .checkboxes" /></th>
                                                                       <th>Username</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th class="hidden-480">Email</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>    
            <th>Activation Key</th>
            <th class="hidden-480">Status</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
           <?php $user_details->all_user_details(); ?>

     </tbody>
</table>
```

Now here is the function i am using. to create table rows. So check this out:

```
while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
                    $single_row ="<tr class=\"odd gradeX\">
                                            <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" class=\"checkboxes\" value=\"".$row["userid"]."\" /></td>
                                            <td>".$row['username']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['fullname']."</td>
                                            <td class=\"hidden-480\"><a href=\"mailto:".$row['email']."\">".$row['email']."</a></td>
                                        <td>".$row['mobile']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['user_activation_key']."</td>";
                                        if($row['status']==1){ 
                                            $single_row .= "<td><span class=\"label label-success\">Approved</span></td>";
                                         } else{ 
                                            $single_row .= "<td><span class=\"label label-danger\">Pending</span></td>"; }
                    $single_row .="</tr>";



                echo $single_row;                   

    }
```

any solution for this problem? I know i am making mistake somewhere in $_POST['checkbox'] while getting the value, Please suggest.

Thank you!

Comment: Mixing GET and POST? What is your code doing / not doing that is wrong?

Comment: I have GET because my delete button is a anchor link and POST i am using because i want to get the value of the checkbox.

Comment: See this Q&A on SO (it may help you), it's where I send everyone for a similar matter. It has helped me and others: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14475096/1415724

Comment: I checked this link, but seems like i am having trouble in reading the checkbox with $_POST in $_GET its showing error of Notice: Undefined index: checkbox

Comment: Where is your `<form>` tag? (you should post it) --- If you're getting that error, then something has obviously not been defined. Is your checkbox named? I.e.: `<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">`

Comment: i dont have a form i just have <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" class=\"checkboxes\" value=\"".$row["userid"]."\" /> in the last function.

Comment: I meant the `<form>` tag. Or is it elsewhere?

Comment: No its no where i didnt use the form tag.

Comment: is there any way i can directly POST a value from simple checkbox like <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" method="post" /> 

something like this?

Comment: There's your problem. Your form elements need to be wrapped inside something to the affect of `<form method="post" action="action_file.php"><input type="checkbox"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">` as an example.

Comment: No, the method must be just like I posted in my above comment.

Comment: if i am using <form> and with <submit> then only its returning in URL http://localhost/somewebsite/allusers.php?delete=Delete2&sample_2_length=10&checkbox[]=7&checkbox[]=8

Answer (score 0):

this is your first problem:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && $_GET['delete']=="true")
{
     $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
     for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
     {
         echo $checkbox[$i]; // here i am going to write delete query
     }
}
```

please change it to this:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
  if ($_GET['delete']=="true") {
     $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
     for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
     {
         echo $checkbox[$i]; // here i am going to write delete query
     }
  }
}
```

and also you forgot to leave a space between **if** and **(**

Comment: don't name it checkbox in $_POST['checkbox']

Comment: change checkbox to for example checkbox1

Comment: you have got this error because you have unchecked checkbox in your form... you have to insert a new if before for loop to check the $checkbox value

Comment: OP doesn't have any `<form></form>` tags. @MehdiJazini that's the main problem. See comments under OP's question.

Comment: something like this: function checkbox_value($name) {
    return (isset($_POST[$name]) ? 1 : 0);
}

Comment: Before submiting the value i am TICKING 2 checkbox.

Comment: @fred ii: and if someone uncheck the checkbox. he will get an error.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_2 .checkboxes" value="" />

Comment: Well, I for one have never seen any form elements work "without" `<form>` @MehdiJazini

Comment: if i am using <form> and with <submit> then only its returning in URL http://localhost/somewebsite/allusers.php?delete=Delete2&sample_2_length=10&checkbox[]=7&checkbox[]=8

Comment: Do what you think will work for you then. Just leave out `<form></form>` then, and hope for the best. I'm done here. @user3201500

Comment: Value is there, actully the value is the "user_id" comming form database table

Comment: as i said: please change name of checkboxes to something like check1 check2 check3 and... and it seems you are sending checkbox values as get not as post!

Comment: you received checkbox[] as GET because PHP have found duplicate checkbox names

Comment: I suggest you to use Notepad++ and to find the problem: please remove all the above lines. and create a very very simple form with a very very simple php code. only 1 data. test it... then add one new line then test it again... and etc... until you find the problem... this is fastest way to resolve your unknown problem. bye

Comment: OK problem solved.  $_GET do not accept $_POST variables. So now i have to make it a form and then it process that way.