# PHP error: Undefined variable

Tags: php, html

I am trying to delete some rows when users check them with check button. I have created a button called delete, but I have a problem. It said to me that variable delete that I use here

```
// Check if delete button active, start this  if($delete){ for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ $del_id = $checkbox[$i]; $sql = "DELETE FROM Aktivitet WHERE Id_Akt='$del_id'"; $result = mysql_query($sql); } is not defined... But why because I have declared it as the name of Delete button...here I have created the Delete button;

  print("<tr>");
    print("<td><input name='delete' type='submit' id='delete' value='Delete'></td>");
    print("</tr>");
```

Please can you help me? What can I do? My php file is below:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Lidhja me databazen nuk mund te kryhet' .mysql_error(). ' </body></html>');
  }
if(!mysql_select_db("Axhenda",$con))
die('Nuk mund te hapet databaza Axhenda'.mysql_error(). '</body></html>');


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Aktiviteti where Data= '$_POST[dataoutput]'");

mysql_close($con);

    ?>

<div class="title"> Aktivitetet per daten <?php print ("$_POST[dataoutput]"); ?></div>

<table> 

<?php

  print("<th >");

   print("<form name='form1' method='post' action=''>");
  print("<td>Emertimi takimit</td>");
   print("<td>Pershkrimi takimit</td>");
    print("<td>Oraa takimit</td>");
    print("</th >");

while($rows=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{

if (!empty($rows))

{

     print("<tr >");


print("<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><input
 name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value='$rows[0]'></td>");
print("<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>$rows[2]</td>");
print("<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>$rows[3]</td>");

print("<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>$rows[5]</td>");

print("</tr>");



    }
 else 
 echo "ska aktivitet";

}
print("<tr>");
print("<td><input name='delete' type='submit' id='delete' value='Delete'></td>");
print("</tr>");


?>
<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this 
if($delete){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM Aktivitet WHERE Id_Akt='$del_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}
// if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php 
if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=delete_multiple.php\">";
}
}  

print("</form>");

?>

</table>
```

I modified the function like below, but it still dont delete anything:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){

    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$count = count($checkbox);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $id = (int) $checkbox[$i]; 

        if ($id > 0) { // and check if it's bigger then 0
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM Aktiviteti WHERE Id_Akt= $id");
        }
    }
}
```

please help me..

Comment: It is not dublicate. I have seen it but in that case the variable is not the name of a form button. IN my case the delete variable that is undefined, is the name of button and I dont know what to do...If it is possible, can you help me?

Comment: @user3272713 - and where do you define `$delete`?

Comment: That what I am asking you? I dont know where and how to define it...Can you help me?

Comment: @user3272713: Why do you need that variable? From the comment in your code, I'm guessing you're trying to `Check if delete button active` - but I don't know what that means. Could you explain?

Comment: I'm going to make a guess that instead of `if ($delete)` you want something along the lines of `if (isset($_POST['delete']))`.

Comment: @andrewsi yes you are right. The error does not appear any more...but my button does not delete anything....even when I check some rows it just redirect me again to that page but not delete anything...Can you help me, please?

Comment: If ID is numeric, then try `WHERE Id_Akt=$del_id";` @user3272713

Comment: @user3272713 - I'll give you a hint. `$delete` isn't set anywhere; what do you think `$checkbox` will do?

Comment: but what can I do? delete is the name of button and checkbox the name of checkbox input....how to set $delete?

Comment: @user3272713 - I get that checkbox is the name of the button. But it doesn't automatically get turned into a variable in PHP that you can access. When you changed `$delete` into `$_POST['delete']`, the error went away. What do you think you need to change `$checkbox` into?

Comment: I modified the function like i just posted above, but it still does not function...please can you help me

Comment: @user3272713 - add some debugging. Is your query being run? If it is, echo it out to see what the values are. Try `var_dump($_POST)` to see exactly what your form is passing. Check the return value from your query to see if it succeeds; if it doesn't check and see what's in `mysql_error()`

Comment: when i try var_dump($_POST) my query output this value :array(1) { ["dataoutput"]=> string(9) "2014-2-11" }. Also it output the table with the activities for that date. the problem is that when I check some dates, it does not delete anything when I press button delete.. When I press it it is like refreshing the page. what canI do?

Comment: When it comes to questions like these, I always refer people to [**This Link on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14475096/) and base yourself on the Q&A inside that page. It's helped me and others before. @user3272713

Comment: I have seen it...And I am seing it now again..But still I havent solve my problem? Have you caught any error in my code? please help me...I have spend hours stuck here...

Comment: I suggest you use the Q&A from the link I provided to you already above, and then modify the variables from there, it will work. Don't spend anymore time in trying to fix your existing code. I don't have time to setup a DB just for this and to debug your code, that's your job. I don't mind helping with obvious errors, but this is too much. @user3272713 - Continue using `var_dump();` for all your variables, you will find what's set and what is not.

Comment: @ Fred can I make you one more question please.. I make it like it is solved in the page you gave to me and it still does not delete anything. But I want to ask you what does this mean: "$result = mysqli_query($sql);"...checked the error logs...found out that mysqli_query() expects at least two parameters.. Because the guy at the other page said that have solved problem with this? What athe parameter should I put in  mysqli_query($sql)???

Comment: This `$result = mysqli_query($sql);` probably needs to have the DB connection added to it. I.e.: `$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);` plus your code uses `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` you can't mix both. So you may have to use `$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);` to match the rest of `mysql_`

Comment: The link I gave you, the person uses `mysqli_*` functions in there, so you will need to change your DB connection method from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`. Notice the added `i` ?

Comment: Also this `$_POST[dataoutput]` you have no form element called `dataoutput` so I don't know how I could piece everything together. I'm totally confused.

Comment: @Fred I made it in onother way. I make a new php file, and when I press the delete button I direct it to that php file and it deletes the checked row. But can I ask you for smth? How can I redirect the new php file to go back to the old one, not to display a blank page whe the wquery is executed?

Comment: What do you mean by *"How can I redirect the new php file to go back to the old one"*? Oh, and I was just about to put something as an answer to help you out, something that I use myself that works. @user3272713

Comment: Oh thanks... you can put it now, for me.If it is not a problem to you...What I mean is that when I press delete button it execute the query, and it sends me to a blank page. But I want that when I press the button, not to go to a blank page but to be at the same page where user can see the table of activities...So it is smth like I press delete button, it execute the query, and it direct me to the page where the calendar and activitis are...I dont know if I am explaining it well,,

Comment: You're welcome. The one I will put up, will redirect you back to the deletion page using `echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;URL=delete.php\">";` so there will be no blank page. @user3272713 yet you will need to make some modifications.

Comment: I would need to see your updated code to see why it's giving you a blank page. @user3272713 - and I posted my answer below.

Comment: I am seeing your answer now...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on my own server. You will need to modify it for your own columns as well as other elements that need to be translated in your language.

**Change settings** for the following:

```
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');  
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
```

**And:** (Note: the `#` is just a reference character. You can change it to what you like.)

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Link ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Link Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Link Email</strong></td>
```

**And change:** (The rows you wish to show up. There are two of these. One is to show the rows, while the other is used for deletion.)

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
```

**And change:** (delete.php is this file to redirect to after deleting)

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;URL=delete.php\">";
```

**And change:** ( `your_table` ) and the `id` depending on which column you want to `ORDER BY`

```
$query = "select * from your_table ORDER BY id ASC";
```

**And change:**

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM your_table WHERE link_id='$del_id'";
```

**And change:** all instances of `link_id` being the `id` (column name) associated with the deletion.

### Full script: (delete.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Choose and delete selected items.</h2>

<?php
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$dbc = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");

$query = "select * from your_table ORDER BY id ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
or die('Error querying database');

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple items</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Link ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Link Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Link Email</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['link_id']; ?>">

</td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
 <tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple items</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Link ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Link Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Link Email</strong></td>
 </tr>

<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['link_id']; ?>">

</td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){

$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM your_table WHERE link_id='$del_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
}
// if successful redirect to delete.php 
if($result){
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;URL=delete.php\">";
// echo "Got results.";
}
 }

mysqli_close($dbc);

?>

</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM Aktivitet WHERE Id_Akt='$del_id'"; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: So if(isset($_post['delete'])) {