# Delete MySQL entry from HTML page

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to design a control page for my website that allows admins to delete requests to use a 3D printer at my school. The page displays a query of the schedule from the MySQL database and puts a delete button next to every entry. However, I would like to link the information in each entry to its respective delete button and have no idea how to do that. You can see the page itself here: http://kepler.covenant.edu/~techclub/PHP/manage%20printer%20schedule.php and this is my code for displaying the information

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    // see if any rows were returned
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // yes
        // print them one after another
        echo "<table cellpadding=10 border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Control</th>";
        echo "<th>Student ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
        echo "<th>First Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Date and Time</th>";
        echo "<th>Description</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $key = 1;
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            echo '<form method="POST" name="deleterequest" action = "delete request.php">';
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><input name='".$row[5]."'type='submit' value='Delete' ></td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else {
        // no
        // print status message
        echo "No upcoming prints found!";
    }

    // free result set memory
    $result->close();
}
```

I can't figure out how to link the information in a row with the delete button that I put in the row to send to the delete request.php program (which I have no code for yet)

Comment: If you're up to using checkboxes, I refer people to [`this Q&A`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14475096/) on SO, which is what I used; it worked for me. Plus, you can change the checkbox to radio; which is what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should put hidden field that hold each record id.

As below

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo '<form method="POST" name="deleterequest" action = "delete request.php">';
            echo "<input name='recored_id' type='hidden' value='".$row['id']."' >";
            echo "<input name='delete'type='submit' value='Delete' >";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
```

Now from your request.php page you should do something like this

```
$recored_id = (int) $_POST['recored_id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE recored_id='$recored_id'";
```

Don't forget to give this code some security validation

all the best,

Comment: This method is open to SQL injection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i know, i mention to do some security stuff :) however i will update it

Comment: Actually, that can also be written as `$recored_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['recored_id']);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are right, but we expect to have integer value in $_POST['recored_id']. so if it's not the query will fill, and this is what we want. however all ways lead to Rome

Comment: ^--« Translated "Rome is a beautiful city!" ;-) - Glad to see the OP accepted your answer. **+1** ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i already translated it with Google translate. you know detect language button is awesome! LoL. Thank you.

Comment: hahaha! ok :) I speak a bit of Italian and other languages. Google Translate does have its advantages. (*You're welcome*) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some hidden inputs, like so:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><form method="POST" name="deleterequest" action = "deleterequest.php">';
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='val0' value='" . $row[0] . "'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='val1' value='" . $row[1] . "'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='val2' value='" . $row[2] . "'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='val3' value='" . $row[3] . "'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='val4' value='" . $row[4] . "'>";
    echo "<input name='".$row[5]."'type='submit' value='Delete' >";
    echo "</form></td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

You should change the name of these inputs though