# Deleting database entries through checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been trying to delete certain rows from the database using a few checkboxes. So far I've managed to echo out the content of the MySQL table but deleting rows through the checkboxes doesn't seem to work.

```
<table class="ts">
        <tr>
            <th class="tg-031e" style='width:1px'>ID</th> 
            <th class="tg-031e">IP address</th>
            <th class="tg-031e">Date added</th>
            <th class="tg-031e">Reason</th>
        </tr>

        <?php include 'connect.php';

            $SQL = "SELECT `ID`, `IPaddress`, `DateAdded`, `Reason` FROM `banned`";
            $exec = mysql_query($SQL, $connection);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec)){
                    echo "<tr class='tg-031h'>";
                    echo "<td class='tg-031e'><form method='post'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value=" . $row['ID'] . "></form></td>";
                    echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['IPaddress'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['DateAdded'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['Reason'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>"; 
            }

            echo "</table><form method='post'><input name='delete' type='submit' value='Delete'></form>";

            if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
                foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $id){
                    $id = (int)$id;
                    $delete = "DELETE FROM banned WHERE ID = $id"; 
                    mysql_query($delete);
                }
            }

            ?>
```

I don't get any result as the check does not pass but I don't know what's wrong with it. The query is correct though, so the issue must be with selecting the checkboxes and getting their ID.

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes are not considered "successful controls" and are thus not submitted to the server. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2 You'll need to pass something else.

Comment: Does anything show up in your HTML with `value=" . $row['ID'] . "`?

Comment: is that separate `<form>` for each checkboxes? And the submit button is also in a separate form?

Comment: Yes, it assigns the proper IDs from the database.

Comment: but if you click submit, form elements from the other forms are not going through...

Comment: Just a hunch; try and remove `&& isset($_POST['checkbox'])`

Comment: Well I tried using one form that surrounds the whole PHP block but it does not submit anything like that.

Comment: Do `echo $delete = "DELETE FROM banned WHERE ID = $id";` see what's being passed through. Plus, are you trying to delete more than one at a time? If so, do `name='checkbox[]'` - either way if it's one or more, you may want to use that instead.

Comment: As I said, this check doesn't even pass. I probably take the checkbox values the wrong way.

Comment: Doing `name='checkbox[]'` didn't work? See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/14475096/ and base yourself on that, which is what I used in the past and it worked for me. It's `mysqli_` mind you.

Comment: Even if I try to delete a single entry, it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Then move your closing brace in your `while` loop right after `mysql_query($delete);`

Comment: @JessieStalk if you submit a form, only elements `inside that form` gets submitted.

Comment: I've tried adding the form before the checkboxes and after the submit button but in that way it doesn't submit anything.

Comment: Any which way, you're using `foreach($_POST['checkbox']` and this requires your checkbox to be treated as an array and your `name='checkbox'` isn't being treated as an array because of missing square brackets as I've already shown you. Whether you're checking one or more. I suggest you look at the link I've given you and base yourself on that, plus using your delete method inside another page. `rlatief` already said it about the form being submitted the way you're doing it now.

Comment: @JessieStalk see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, it's tested and working while using `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_`

Replace with your own credentials.

A few things, your checkbox did need square brackets around the named element as I mentioned in my comment(s), i.e. `name='checkbox[]'`
 otherwise you would receive an invalid `foreach` argument error.

Sidenote: There stands to do a bit of formatting, but it  works.

```
<table class="ts">
        <tr>
            <th class="tg-031e" style='width:1px'>ID</th> 
            <th class="tg-031e">IP address</th>
            <th class="tg-031e">Date added</th>
            <th class="tg-031e">Reason</th>
        </tr>

<?php

$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";

$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}

$SQL = "SELECT `ID`, `IPaddress`, `DateAdded`, `Reason` FROM `banned`";
$exec = mysqli_query($con,$SQL);

echo "<form method='post'>";

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
                echo "<tr class='tg-031h'>";
                echo "<td class='tg-031e'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='" . $row[ID] . "'></td>";

                echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['IPaddress'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['DateAdded'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['Reason'] . "</td>";
        }

echo "</tr></table>"; 

        echo "<input name='delete' type='submit' value='Delete'></form>";

        if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
            foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $id){
                $id = (int)$id;

                $delete = "DELETE FROM banned WHERE ID = $id"; 
                mysqli_query($con,$delete);
            }
        }

?>
```

---

Do use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) for this.

---

**Edit:** `mysql_` version

```
<table class="ts">
        <tr>
            <th class="tg-031e" style='width:1px'>ID</th> 
            <th class="tg-031e">IP address</th>
            <th class="tg-031e">Date added</th>
            <th class="tg-031e">Reason</th>
        </tr>

<?php

include 'connect.php';

$SQL = "SELECT `ID`, `IPaddress`, `DateAdded`, `Reason` FROM `banned`";
$exec = mysql_query($SQL, $connection);

echo "<form method='post'>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec)){
                echo "<tr class='tg-031h'>";
                echo "<td class='tg-031e'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='" . $row[ID] . "'></td>";

                echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['IPaddress'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['DateAdded'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['Reason'] . "</td>";
        }

echo "</tr></table>"; 

        echo "<input name='delete' type='submit' value='Delete'></form>";

        if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
            foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $id){
                $id = (int)$id;

                $delete = "DELETE FROM banned WHERE ID = $id"; 
                mysql_query($delete);
            }
        }

?>
```

Comment: @JessieStalk `mysqli_` isn't available for you in that version?

Comment: @JessieStalk I've modified it to be as you had it, using `mysql_` - See under my **Edit**

Answer (score 0):

You should do something similar to this (semi pseudo):

```
<form method="post">

    /begin loop/

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="row[' . $row['ID'] . ']" />';

    /end loop/

    <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Then try to put this on the processor page, on top of it:

```
if ( !empty( $_POST ) )
{
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $_POST, true ) . '</pre>';
    die( 'see? :-)' );
}
```

.
.
.
.

Okay here's your code, edited:

```
<?php if ( !empty( $_POST ) ) { echo '<pre>'.print_r( $_POST, true ).'</pre>'; die( 'See?' ); ?>
<form method="post">
<table class="ts">
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-031e" style='width:1px'>ID</th> 
        <th class="tg-031e">IP address</th>
        <th class="tg-031e">Date added</th>
        <th class="tg-031e">Reason</th>
    </tr>

    <?php include 'connect.php';

        $SQL = "SELECT `ID`, `IPaddress`, `DateAdded`, `Reason` FROM `banned`";
        $exec = mysql_query($SQL, $connection);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec)){
                echo "<tr class='tg-031h'>";
                echo "<td class='tg-031e'><input type='checkbox' name='row[$row['ID']]'></td>";
                echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['IPaddress'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['DateAdded'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['Reason'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>"; 
        }

        echo "</table><input name='delete' type='submit' value='Delete'>";

        if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
            foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $id){
                $id = (int)$id;
                $delete = "DELETE FROM banned WHERE ID = $id"; 
                mysql_query($delete);
            }
        }

        ?>

</form>
```

The Deletion query hasn't been fixed yet. Try to fix it yourself :-)

Comment: Sorry I don't see how this can help me. Why should I display any $_POST content?

Comment: To see the posted data that'll help you build the query. Remove it after you understand it.

Comment: The basic mistake is, you have 1 form for every checkboxes. And also a separate form for the button. If you click the button, only the button element that'll get POSTed. You cannot submit more than 1 form at a time (without using some out of topic workaround).

Comment: That's why I asked on stackoverflow. It is by far the only thing that hinders the code but I can't figure how to or where to define the form first and where to close it.

Comment: Yes, you need to put all the checkboxes and the submit button into a single form. The code above should work. If it doesn't then there's a typo somewhere (that's why I prefer to explain by using pseudo as in the first two code blocks).

Comment: `I can't figure how to or where to define the form first and where to close it`

Comment: Define `<form>` before the table, and `</form>` after it. Putting `form` tags inside the table, between the `tr`, will work, but it'll make your HTML invalid. Putting `<form>` and `</form>` inside the same `<td>` is valid HTML, but you won't be able to achieve what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok, let's leave it at that.