# Selecting multiple items to perform a task

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to select multiple items to delete the records in the database. But i am not being able to. My `delete.php` is fine. How can i use it to delete multiple selected items. I just created a checkbox. How can i make that checkbox work.

```
echo"<TR><TD>Select</td><TD>S.N.</td><td><B>Full Name</B></td><td><B>Options</B></td></TR>";
while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox'name='mycheck'onclick='toggleform('document.myform','mycheck','ptext')'></td>";
    echo "<TD>".$myrow['id']."</TD>";
    echo "<TD>".$myrow['name']." </TD>";
    echo "<TD><a href=\"view1.php?id=".$myrow['id']."\">View</a> ";
    echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=".$myrow['id']."\">Delete</a> ";
    echo "<a href=\"edit1.php?id=".$myrow['id']."\">Edit</a>";
}
<input type="button" name= "ptext" value="Delete selected">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete multiple rows by selecting checkboxes using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475096/delete-multiple-rows-by-selecting-checkboxes-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `checkbox name` as `array` type i.e. `mycheck[]`. Then, In **delete_all.php** page, find total checked checkbox and delete it accordingly.

```
<form method='POST' action="delete_all.php">

    <?php
    echo"<TR><TD>Select</td><TD>S.N.</td><td><B>Full Name</B></td><td><B>Options</B></td></TR>";
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
          echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='mycheck[]' value=".$myrow['id']."></td>";
          echo "<TD>".$myrow['id']."</TD>";
          echo "<TD>".$myrow['name']." </TD>";
          echo "<TD><a href=\"view1.php?id=".$myrow['id']."\">View</a> ";
          echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=".$myrow['id']."\">Delete</a> ";
          echo "<a href=\"edit1.php?id=".$myrow['id']."\">Edit</a>";
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name= "ptext" value="Delete selected">

</form>
```

**delete_all.php**

```
<?
extract($_POST);

$totalCheckboxChecked = sizeof($mycheck);

for($i=0;$i<$totalCheckboxChecked;$i++)
{
    $idToDelete = $mycheck[$i];

    echo "DELETE FROM table_Name WHERE id_ColumnName = '$idToDelete'";

    // Execute Your Querys
}
?>
```

Comment: undefined variable mycheck in delete_all.php.

Comment: That solved. how can i disable that 'delete selected' button until i check one.

Comment: That's different question @micky. Please ask  new question or you can search in SO. There are lot of examples given. *Thanks.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting all ids on the delete.php page? if yes then simple use

```
DELETE FROM tableName
WHERE id IN ($id1 , $id2 , $id3 , etc);
```

if not, The way i would do it is, i would use form, and then post it in the delete.php page using method post, and then simply take the values from super global

```
$_POST[]
```

and use the above query, hope this helps.